# How do I make Gnome (and Gnome applications) automatically detect a wvdial connection?

Tags: gnome, networking

I use wvdial in order to connect to the internet using a cdma usb modem that isn't detected by the nm-applet.

However, once I've connected, gnome and other gnome applications don't seem able to determine that I am connected to the internet. (e.g. empathy, ubuntu one remain offline,  firefox "work offline" has to be disabled manually)

The desired effect is:  I connect via wvdial and gnome detects this and enables everything appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 possible solutions:

1. make NetworkManager recognize your CDMA modem (via [ModemManager](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/ModemManager/ModemManager/tree/))
2. make wvdial support the [NetworkManager dbus protocol](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/docs/NetworkManager%20DBUS%20API.txt)
3. find another tool that supports both

Comment: Thanks for all the excellent info.  Option 2 is particularly appealing (though I was initially hoping to avoid it) because it means I might get to contribute some code.

Comment: Actually, the best solution would be 1 or maybe 3.  If you're very lucky it works the same as or very similar to an already supported modem, but isn't recognised as such.  As for option "3", you might want to try ConnMan (Ubuntu Netbook Edition 10.10 will probably use that).